# Default value Form control Combobox still present after selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic combobox setup (Form Controls) which all are dependent on each other. The selection in one combobox trigger the next items of the next combobox. In some cases there is only one item to be populated in one of the comboboxes, that made the combobox1_ change() event not be triggered. SO in the end I populated a default value for each combobox, like "choose". However that item or default value would not disappear after one selects an item from the combobox, in other words it always present.

```
Sub Dropdown16()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Dashboard")
Dim DD14 As DropDown

Set DD14 = ws.DropDowns("Drop Down 16")

DD14.Text = "Choose"

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not following the logic, here. It looks like you're trying to add the "default" in the control's change event? That doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: Maybe that is the problem :)

Comment: Ok, so now I populated combobox with text = " Choose"  and not in change event but it does not seems to be removed when selecting other value in that combobox..any solutions ?

Comment: Please update the question with the current code and provide a [mcve] so that it's possible to test what you're doing.

Comment: Ok, updated now..

Comment: You need to also include the code that's not working, the change event. In the change event the item to be deleted should be removed from the list.